# Finding unique values in a dataset for market basket analysis in csv file

Tags: r

I am doing market basket analysis,the datasheet consist grocery items,i want to find out how many unique items are there?please help me

Comment: Please show us your data to help you better

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please hover over the R tag - it asks for a minimal reproducible example. [Here's a guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610); also have a look at the R help files (e.g. `help(p="arules")`). After that, edit & improve your question accordingly. A good one usually provides minimal input data, the desired output data, code tries incl required packages - all copy-paste-run'able in a new/clean R session. *Why?* It makes it easier for all to follow and participate.

Answer (score 0):

Consider for example:

```
# create demo comma-separated file:
library(arules)
data(Groceries)
lst <- as(Groceries, "list")
writeLines(sapply(lst, paste, collapse=","), tf<-tempfile(fileext = ".csv"))
# readLines(tf)[1:3]
# # [1] "citrus fruit,semi-finished bread,margarine,ready soups"
# # [2] "tropical fruit,yogurt,coffee"                          
# # [3] "whole milk" 

# load csv and check number of items
trans <- read.transactions(tf,"basket",sep=",")
trans
# transactions in sparse format with
#  9835 transactions (rows) and
#  169 items (columns)
ncol(trans)
# [1] 169
```